# Trying to install yeoman on ubuntu to use with nodejs and npm

Tags: 13.10, nodejs, npm

Using Ubuntu 13.10

I am trying to install yeoman using `sudo npm install -g yo` but it doesn't seem to work globally  both `npm` and `nodejs` are installed, however, I am not sure that they are installed correctly for use globally.  I cannot use `npm` i have to use `sudo npm`

To install node js I used

```
    $ sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
    $ sudo apt-add-repository ppa:chris-lea/node.js
    $ sudo apt-get update
    $ sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

When I use `sudo npm install -g yo` the output I get is

```
    /usr/bin/yo -> /usr/lib/node_modules/yo/cli.js

    > yo@1.2.1 postinstall /usr/lib/node_modules/yo
    > node ./scripts/doctor

    [Yeoman Doctor] Everything looks alright!

    yo@1.2.1 /usr/lib/node_modules/yo
    ├── is-root@0.1.0
    ├── fullname@0.1.1
    ├── opn@0.1.2
    ├── async@0.9.0
    ├── shelljs@0.3.0
    ├── lodash@2.4.1
    ├── multiline@0.3.4 (strip-indent@0.1.3)
    ├── sudo-block@0.4.0 (chalk@0.4.0)
    ├── nopt@3.0.1 (abbrev@1.0.5)
    ├── chalk@0.5.1 (escape-string-regexp@1.0.1, ansi-styles@1.1.0, supports-           color@0.2.0, strip-ansi@0.3.0, has-ansi@0.1.0)
    ├── string-length@0.1.2 (strip-ansi@0.2.2)
    ├── findup@0.1.5 (commander@2.1.0, colors@0.6.2)
    ├── yosay@0.3.0 (ansi-regex@0.2.1, pad-component@0.0.1, ansi-styles@1.1.0, word- 
    wrap@0.1.3, strip-ansi@0.2.2, minimist@0.2.0, chalk@0.4.0, taketalk@0.1.1)
    ├── update-notifier@0.2.0 (semver-diff@0.1.0, latest-version@0.2.0,    

    configstore@0.3.1)
    ├── insight@0.3.1 (object-assign@0.1.2, chalk@0.4.0, async@0.2.10,    
    lodash.debounce@2.4.1, inquirer@0.4.1, request@2.27.0, configstore@0.2.3)
    └── yeoman-generator@0.17.2 (dargs@0.1.0, github-username@0.1.1, diff@1.0.8,  
    class-extend@0.1.1, rimraf@2.2.8, chalk@0.4.0, text-table@0.2.0, mime@1.2.11,  
    isbinaryfile@2.0.1, debug@1.0.4, grouped-queue@0.3.0, mkdirp@0.5.0,    
    underscore.string@2.3.3, glob@4.0.5, iconv-lite@0.2.11, findup-sync@0.1.3, file-
    utils@0.2.0, download@0.1.18, cheerio@0.17.0, request@2.39.0, gruntfile-
    editor@0.1.1, inquirer@0.5.1)
```

So it appears that yeoman is installed correctly but that it isn't working - when I type yo nothing happens...  Do I need to put yo in my `$PATH`?  I'm not really sure how to do that..  Additionally, how do I configure `npm` so I don't have to use `sudo npm`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's worth noting that Ubuntu 13.10 is no longer officially supported, but that shouldn't make much of a difference for these instructions.

### npm without sudo

First things first, let's get permissions sorted out. Most of the Node.js installation guides for Ubuntu instruct you to install Node.js from either the official repositories or from the chris-lea PPA. Either way, you'll end up installing Node.js and NPM using `sudo`, which leads to a permissions mess on development machines.

There's [a question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16151018/388639) about how to "fix" these permissions, although in most cases, you'll have to make your user the owner of `/usr/local/lib/node_modules`, which is super sketchy.

Instead, I think the best answer by far is to [install Node.js using NVM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24404451/388639). In addition to letting you run multiple versions of Node.js on the same computer, this option also keeps everything in your home folder, so your user owns NPM, and you don't have to mess around with `sudo npm`.

### Using Yo

Once your permissions are sorted out, all of the steps you took to install and run Yeoman (`npm install -g yo`) should work just fine.

You will have to run `nvm use v0.10` each time you start a new terminal session, however. You can get around this by adding a script to your `.bashrc` that will automatically run this for you at the beginning of each session,

Answer (score 0):

You should check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16151018/npm-throws-error-without-sudo)

it solves this problem